# Why do I need to write "javascript:" before a function name?

Tags: javascript

If I want to use an external javascipt function like "functionname()", see the example below:

```
<from onSubmit="javascript: funtionname()" >
</form>
```

why do I need sometimes to write javascript: before the function name?

Comment: As the others said, it is *not* needed. And you should avoid executing JavaScript "as URL" anyways (bad design).

Comment: Yes. java script is not required.

Answer (score 3):

In handlers (`onclick`, `onchange`, etc.), you don't have to use the prefix. For these, Javascript is already expected and the prefix is interpreted as a label and has no effect.

If you want to execute Javascript in an `href` attribute for example, the prefix "javascript:" *is* needed. Otherwise the value would be interpreted as a URL.

In general, though, this practice should be avoided as it contradicts [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) policy.

Answer (score 2):

The `javascript:` notation is a URL scheme, and may be used wherever a URL is expected. As far as I am aware, passing a URL to an event handler is incorrect (at least according to the HTML5 spec) though browsers appear to support it. You are expected to specify a valid function or null as an event handler. The browser may be interpreting this javascript prefix as a label, though it might be technically incorrect to allow this.

Comment: FWIW, syntactically it is allowed to put `javascript:` there. Don't confuse the HTML `onclick` attribute with the element node's `onclick` property. The attribute can contain any valid JavaScript. This code will become the body of a function, but the browser will take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

You will need to write `javascript:` when you using an url type tag only (like: `href` and `src`), to specify that the string need to eval a javascript code.

Example:

```
<a href="javascript: doSomething();">
    My link is a javascript function doSomething()
</a>
```

You can:

```
<form onSubmit="doSomething();">
    When submit the form, will ran doSomething, 
    if returns false will cancel the form submission
</form>
```

Comment: Not technically correct. As my answer suggests, you can use the javascript: notation wherever a URL can be specified, such as the src element of an img tag <img src="javascript:generateImageUrl(Math.round(100*Math.random()))">

Answer (score 0):

No need to do it in handlers. It is used only as protocol in URL-like method, e.g.:

```
<a href="javascript:funtionname()">Click here</a>
```